# How do I disable comments globally on a Google Site?

Tags: comments, google-classic-sites

In Google Sites, I can disable comments for a page by clicking Settings, Page Settings, and unchecking "Allow comments". How do I uncheck this option for all pages at once, i.e. disable comments globally on my site? Do I need to disable comments on a per-page basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Short answer

There isn't a global setting for comments in Google Sites, so the comments should be disabled page by page.

## Extended answer

You could disable the comments option page by page manually. Unfortunately looks that there isn't a method to do this automatically by using Google Apps Script.

To avoid this problem in the future, create a page template with the comments option disabled then use it to create the new pages.

## References

- [Sites Service Overview - Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/)
- [Disable comments when creating a page from script (Google Apps Script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648549/disable-comments-when-creating-a-page-from-script-google-apps-script)